# query running for 60+ minutes, optimization tips

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I am retrieving  economic data for about 1 million records , while combining results from few tables. It seems that with that many records in 
DEAL_EVENT and DEAL tables the query runs extremely long: 60+ minutes. 
i am looking for tip to optimize the query.
Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1f01a/1
I have also tried with parallel execution using

```
WITH
OWNER AS (
 SELECT 
   DISTINCT OWNER.ID
 FROM 
   BUSINESS_PARTNER OWNED
   JOIN OWNERS_TO_COUNTERPARTY L ON OWNED.ID = L.COUNTERPARTY
   JOIN PARTY OWNER ON OWNER.ID = L.OWNER
 WHERE 
  OWNED.TYPE IN (8, 12) 
  AND OWNER.TYPE IN (2, 17)
)
```

which improves it significantly , but the issue is: the query needs to work on both MySQL and Oracle

I have already created indexes on all seemingly relevant columns as well as run SQL Tuning Advisor and also implemented suggested indexes which were:

```
DEAL_EVENT("SOMESECURITY","TYPE");
DEAL_EVENT("SOMESECURITY","VALUE_DATE");
PARTY("TYPE","ID");
```

I have also changed SELECT from multiple tables to one table with multiple left joins. I also tested with removal of SUM statements from the select.
All with little improvement. It is worth noting that one of the SUM will always return 0 and the other is used to simply flip sign because SELLER_DIRECTION is either -1 or 1 always.

The fidle link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1f01a/1/0

```sql
SELECT CT.TYPE AS DEAL_TYPE, TI.DIV_REQ, NULL AS POSITION_CURRENCY, CT.EXTP_ID, BP.ID AS OWNER_ID, BP.TYPE AS OWNER_TYPE, SUM(ABS(CT.SELLER - BP.ID)) AS IS_SELLER, 
TI.FIN_SEC, 
(SELECT SI.CU_DEPO FROM SETTLEMENT_INSTRUCTION SI WHERE EV.OWN_SETTLEMENT_INSTRUCTION = SI.ID) AS SELLER_CU_DEPO, 

CT.SELL_DEPO, CT.TRADING_BOOK, EV.SETTLEMENT_STATUS, EV.CHANGE_FUNC, 
SUM(EV.AMOUNT * EV.SELLER_DIRECTION) AS AMOUNT, 
NULL AS SSTYPE, CT.ORIGIN AS REPO_ORIGIN, EV.EVENT_DATE AS EVENT_DATE, EV.VALUE_DATE AS VALUE_DATE, 
(SELECT CE.NEW_RATE FROM DEAL_EVENT CE WHERE CE.TYPE = 21 AND CE.SOMESECURITY = TI.ID AND CE.IS_REVERSED = 0 AND CE.VALUE_DATE = 
            ( SELECT MAX(EVENT.VALUE_DATE) 
                        FROM DEAL_EVENT EVENT, SOMESECURITY TII 
                            WHERE TII.ID = EVENT.SOMESECURITY AND EVENT.TYPE=21 AND TII.ID = TI.ID AND EVENT.IS_REVERSED = 0 AND EVENT.VALUE_DATE <= TO_DATE('09-07-2019', 'dd-MM-YYYY'))) AS NEWRATE,
            CASE WHEN CT.RECALL_PERIOD IS NOT NULL THEN CT.RECALL_PERIOD ELSE AG.RECALL_PERIOD END AS RECALL_PERIOD, 
            AG.ID AS AGREEMENT_ID, 
            BUYER.TYPE AS BUYER_TYPE,
            CT.MTYPE AS MTYPE, 
            CT.BANK_ACCOUNT AS BANK_ACCOUNT 
            FROM DEAL CT, SOMESECURITY TI, DEAL_EVENT EV, PARTY BP, AGREEMENT AG, PARTY BUYER 
        WHERE CT.ID = TI.DEAL AND AG.ID = CT.AGREEMENT AND BP.ID = CT.SELLER AND 
        BP.ID IN (
                SELECT DISTINCT OWNER.ID FROM PARTY OWNED JOIN OWNERS_TO_COUNTERPARTY L ON OWNED.ID=L.COUNTERPARTY JOIN PARTY OWNER ON OWNER.ID = L.OWNER WHERE OWNED.TYPE IN (8,12) AND OWNER.TYPE IN (2,17)) 
                AND EV.IS_REVERSED = 0 AND CT.TYPE IN (1, 3, 4, 8, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 31, 32, 50, 51) 
                AND TI.TYPE IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 10, 13, 15) 
                AND CT.BUYER = BUYER.ID AND EV.SETTLEMENT_STATUS = 2 
                AND TI.ID = EV.SOMESECURITY 
        GROUP BY CT.TYPE, CT.ORIGIN, TI.DIV_REQ, CT.EXTP_ID, CT.SELL_DEPO, EV.SETTLEMENT_STATUS, EV.CHANGE_FUNC, BP.TYPE, BP.ID, TI.FIN_SEC, EV.OWN_SETTLEMENT_INSTRUCTION, CT.TRADING_BOOK, EVENT_DATE, VALUE_DATE, TI.ID, CASE WHEN CT.RECALL_PERIOD IS NOT NULL THEN CT.RECALL_PERIOD ELSE AG.RECALL_PERIOD END, AG.ID, BUYER.TYPE, CT.MTYPE, CT.BANK_ACCOUNT ORDER BY TI.FIN_SEC;
```

I would expect this query to be computed relatively fast as the data retrieved itself is not complex but I believe it suffers serious design issues that cause multiple loops

Comment: At least for oracle, run an explain plan and edit/post the results

Comment: Or even better, a SQL Monitor report. Explain plan only shows what the optimizer thinks it might do; a SQL Monitor report will show you what it actually did. Then you can see where time is being spent and hopefully why. Only then, can you come up with a remedy.

Comment: The construct `AND CE.VALUE_DATE = ( SELECT MAX(EVENT.VALUE_DATE)  ...)` can probably be improved with `MAX..KEEP()` or (on 12.1 or later) a `CROSS APPLY ( ... ORDER BY EVENT.VALUE_DATE DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY)`.

Comment: In addition to the explain plan, what is the cardinality of the `OWNED.TYPE` and `OWNER.TYPE` columns?  If just a small number of distinct `TYPE`s you may want a bitmapped index, but be aware if there is a lot of data updates/inserts/deletes on the table that can cause locking.

Comment: OWNER.TYPE has only a few values

Answer (score 0):

Run the below query with your large data set it will reduce processing time.

1. Replace In clause from your query. It always does round trip, compares each row with 
    the values return by inner query.
2. Next use joins instead using cardinality.
3. Use lookup tables to filter TYPE ids and join them.

---

```
SELECT CT.TYPE AS DEAL_TYPE, TI.DIV_REQ, NULL AS POSITION_CURRENCY, CT.EXTP_ID, BP.ID AS OWNER_ID, BP.TYPE AS OWNER_TYPE,
 SUM(ABS(CT.SELLER - BP.ID)) AS IS_SELLER, 
                    TI.FIN_SEC, 
                    (SELECT SI.CU_DEPO FROM SETTLEMENT_INSTRUCTION SI WHERE EV.OWN_SETTLEMENT_INSTRUCTION = SI.ID) AS SELLER_CU_DEPO,         
                    CT.SELL_DEPO, CT.TRADING_BOOK, EV.SETTLEMENT_STATUS, EV.CHANGE_FUNC, 
                    SUM(EV.AMOUNT * EV.SELLER_DIRECTION) AS AMOUNT, 
                    NULL AS SSTYPE, CT.ORIGIN AS REPO_ORIGIN, EV.EVENT_DATE AS EVENT_DATE, EV.VALUE_DATE AS VALUE_DATE, 
                    (SELECT CE.NEW_RATE FROM DEAL_EVENT CE WHERE CE.TYPE = 21 AND CE.SOMESECURITY = TI.ID AND CE.IS_REVERSED = 0 AND CE.VALUE_DATE = 
                                ( SELECT MAX(EVENT.VALUE_DATE) 
                                            FROM DEAL_EVENT EVENT, SOMESECURITY TII 
                                                WHERE TII.ID = EVENT.SOMESECURITY AND EVENT.TYPE=21 AND TII.ID = TI.ID 
                                                AND EVENT.IS_REVERSED = 0 AND
                                                EVENT.VALUE_DATE <= TO_DATE('09-07-2019', 'dd-MM-YYYY'))) AS NEWRATE,
                                CASE WHEN CT.RECALL_PERIOD IS NOT NULL THEN CT.RECALL_PERIOD ELSE AG.RECALL_PERIOD END
                                AS RECALL_PERIOD, 
                                AG.ID AS AGREEMENT_ID, 
                                BUYER.TYPE AS BUYER_TYPE,
                                CT.MTYPE AS MTYPE, 
                                CT.BANK_ACCOUNT AS BANK_ACCOUNT 
                                FROM DEAL CT
                                JOIN SOMESECURITY TI ON CT.ID = TI.DEAL
                                JOIN DEAL_EVENT EV ON TI.ID = EV.SOMESECURITY 
                                JOIN PARTY BP ON BP.ID = CT.SELLER
                                JOIN AGREEMENT AG ON AG.ID = CT.AGREEMENT
                                JOIN PARTY BUYER ON CT.BUYER = BUYER.ID
                                JOIN (
                                    SELECT DISTINCT OWNER.ID FROM PARTY OWNED JOIN OWNERS_TO_COUNTERPARTY L ON OWNED.ID=L.COUNTERPARTY JOIN PARTY OWNER ON OWNER.ID = L.OWNER WHERE OWNED.TYPE IN (8,12) AND OWNER.TYPE IN (2,17)
                                    ) TEMP_OID ON BP.ID = TEMP_OID.ID
                            WHERE  EV.IS_REVERSED = 0 AND 
                            --PUT Thease type in a look up table and join it here In cluase always a slow process.
                            CT.TYPE IN (1, 3, 4, 8, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 31, 32, 50, 51) 
                                    AND TI.TYPE IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 10, 13, 15) -- Create lookup table for this one as well
                                    AND EV.SETTLEMENT_STATUS = 2 
                            GROUP BY CT.TYPE, CT.ORIGIN, TI.DIV_REQ, CT.EXTP_ID, CT.SELL_DEPO, EV.SETTLEMENT_STATUS, EV.CHANGE_FUNC, BP.TYPE, BP.ID, TI.FIN_SEC, EV.OWN_SETTLEMENT_INSTRUCTION, CT.TRADING_BOOK, EVENT_DATE, VALUE_DATE, TI.ID, CASE WHEN CT.RECALL_PERIOD IS NOT NULL THEN CT.RECALL_PERIOD ELSE AG.RECALL_PERIOD END, AG.ID, BUYER.TYPE, CT.MTYPE, CT.BANK_ACCOUNT ORDER BY TI.FIN_SEC;
```

Comment: you have used tables like table1 t1, table2 it does cross join t1*t2. then you are filtering product of those tables.

Answer (score 0):

in the end the suggestions did not help. I think there is a deeper problem with data constellation and a redesign might be useful. What worked is using db specific tricks. For oracle it was using the WITH statement:

```
 WITH
OWNER AS (
 SELECT 
   DISTINCT OWNER.ID
 FROM 
   PARTY OWNED
   JOIN OWNERS_TO_COUNTERPARTY L ON OWNED.ID = L.COUNTERPARTY
   JOIN PARTY OWNER ON OWNER.ID = L.OWNER
 WHERE 
  OWNED.TYPE IN (8, 12) 
  AND OWNER.TYPE IN (2, 17)
)
-- MAIN SELECT STATEMENT
  SELECT 
         CT.TYPE
```